SONOFF ZBMINIL2 Installation
I have a one way switch (UK lighting) and want to try out the SONOFF ZBMINIL2 2 way switch relay for home automation.
Diagram and wiring instructions
I think I need to put the live wire in the "live in" and then the switch wire (with tape around it) into the "live out" . Then I think I need to connect S1 to the "live" port on the back of the light switch and S2 to where the switch wire is currently connected to ("1 way").
There is no neutral and the switch is for a bathroom so it's on the outside of the room and powers spotlights.


According to the instructions, you have described exactly what needs to happen. The relay gets your power wire to the line in, and the wire to the light on the line out. Your existing switch connects arbitrarily to the S1/S2 connections. Order does not matter on S1/S2.

Hey thanks for this. Two forums and about 10 useless comments later i got a straight answer. Really appreciate it.
